# Accessing main arguments from a static initializer

Tags: java, log4j

Given:

```
public class MyClass {

   static {
     // Access to args is needed here
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
   }
}
```

I'd like to access args in the above mentioned static block.

I'm aware that the static block is executed when the class is loaded (or initialized) and before the static main function, but was still wondering whether it was possible to access its args.

Btw - my end goal is to append to the name of the log file at run-time, before log4j is configured (using system property variable that is derived from one of the arguments that is passed to main).

Comment: No, but you can rely on system properties directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a special system property "sun.java.command" that contains whole command line.

Here is an example:

```
static {
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("sun.java.command"));
}
```

When I ran my program with arguments `aaa bbb` I got the following output:

```
com.MyClass aaa bbb
```

Comment: BTW — Do you know if this is independent of the implementation of the virtual machine?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that this is for Sun/Oracle JVM. I believe however that this is supported by OpenJDK and I have not idea what about the IBM and JRokit.

Comment: I just wonder if this is an antipattern or not. On the one had we're bypassing the injection chain of the args array, but on the other hand static initializers being invoked on classloading, which in turn happens prior to execution of the main method seems logically unnecessary.

Comment: I confirm it works in IBM JDK, Tested in version 1.8.0_291 i386 & x86_x64

Comment: One mistake in my previous comment, it works in Semeru JDK, it does not work inside iSeries

Answer (score 5):

You cant access arguments of main from static block. Instead (or inaddition) of passing arguments to main, i would suggest you use System parameter like:

```
java -Dmyvar=value ...
```

And access it within static block like

```
static {
    String parameterValue = System.getProperty("myvar");
    ...
}
```